# Want the visual style in wordpress

Tags: visual-editor, wysiwyg

In my WordPress installation when I want to post something there are only html style to write.

I see in video tutorial that a WYSIWYG editor should appear on the screen so I can write easily as I write in word processor.

So seems the visual editor in missing from my post edit screen. How do I get that back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dashboard>>Users>>Edit User:` is "Disable the visual editor when writing" ticked?

Comment: I don’t see this option in user profiles anymore.

Comment: @toscho, Really? I see it in 3.8 on all my sites.

Comment: See http://i.stack.imgur.com/dSbp3.png

Comment: Weird; why do I see it? http://imgur.com/j3G9swB

Comment: Ah, this is available on single-site installations only. Looks like a bug. _Edit_ No, I see it on some multi-site installation, not on all.

Comment: Interesting; does this seem to be a bug? Doesn't look to be anything in trac.worpdress.org about it.

Answer (score 2):

The editor have two tabs to switch from visual to html (text) and back, see the screenshot, is more understandable.

[image]